# How can I access the recovery mode when command+r isn't working

Tags: macos

My MacBook is stuck at at welcome screen. My recovery mode wouldn't display whenever I pressed the key combinations "command+R". Please I need help

Comment: Is your keyboard not working or your internet not working? It’s not precisely clear what you need help with b

Comment: Both my keyboard and internet are working. My problem is; my computer freezes whenever I selects my user account, so I'm trying to fix the os using the recovery mode but it wouldn't respond whenever I press "command+R".